textarea inside a `<td>` element is not responding to click events
I have a table with 6 columns. In one of the row cells I am using a textarea element to display and capture user input.
Currently, the content inside the text area is truncated and an ellipse is applied. The interaction that I'm looking for is when the user clicks into the textarea, the textarea is expanded to fit the whole content and the text can be updated.
The problem I run up against is when you try to update the content in the textarea. For long content strings you cannot click on the wrapped text lines in the textarea, and actually the text cursor doesn't appear after the first line.This is even when adjusting for row={n}.
What can be the issue here? Is the table cell somehow interfering with the click handling? I also notice that if I place an onClick handler on the textarea it doesn't trigger beyond the first line of content.
This component is inside a <td> element
function DescriptionColumnCell({ initialValue }: { initialValue: string }) {
  const [description, setDescription] = useState(initialValue);
  const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState(false);
  const textareaRef = useRef<HTMLTextAreaElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setDescription(initialValue);
  }, [initialValue]);

  useEffect(() => {
    adjustTextareaHeight();
  }, [description]);

  const adjustTextareaHeight = () => {
    if (textareaRef.current) {
      textareaRef.current.style.height = 'auto';
      textareaRef.current.style.height = `${textareaRef.current.scrollHeight}px`;
    }
  };

  const handleFocus = () => {
    console.log('handleFocus');
    setIsFocused(true);
    adjustTextareaHeight();
  };

  const handleChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
    setDescription(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleClick = (event: React.MouseEvent) => {
    console.log('event', event);
    adjustTextareaHeight();
  };
  const handleMouseDown = (event: React.MouseEvent) => {
    console.log('event', event);
  };

  const handleOnClick = (event: React.MouseEvent) => {
    console.log('handleOnClick', event);
    event.stopPropagation();
    setIsFocused(true);
  };

  return (
    <div className={`${styles['description-column-cell']} ${isFocused ? styles['focused'] : ''}`}>
      <div
        className={`${styles['input-element']}`}
        onClick={handleOnClick}
      >
        <textarea
          ref={textareaRef}
          onClick={handleClick}
          value={description}
          placeholder="description"
          onChange={handleChange}
          onFocus={handleFocus}
          rows={1}
          style={{ overflow: 'hidden' }}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

and the CSS
.description-column-cell {
  position: relative;
  height: 34px;

  .input-element {
    width: 100%;
    height: 34px;

    textarea {
      width: 100%;
      height: 34px;
      padding-block: 8px;
      padding-inline: 16px;

      font-size: var(--12px);
      line-height: var(--leading-normal);
      color: var(--text-primary);

      border: none;
      background-color: transparent;

      white-space: nowrap;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;

      resize: none;
      display: block;
    }
  }

  &.focused {
    .input-element {
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 100;

      textarea {
        max-height: 200px;
        white-space: normal;
        overflow: auto;
        background-color: var(--background-primary);
        box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
        outline: 1px solid var(--border-tertiary);
        cursor: text;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 101;
      }
    }
  }
}

UPDATE: I removed the position: relative from the .description-column-cell, which moved the component to the next closest element with position: relative. Turns out to be a <ul> tag with a height of 24px. The textarea is now registering events and the second line is showing the text cursor icon on hover over. Looks like there is some issue (or missing CSS property) with <td> that is causing this (??)
UPDATE2: position: fixed on the .description-column-cell enabled the textarea second line to be clickable, cursor text, and registered events. With a fixed position the issue now is setting the width to the parent <td> so that it doesn't extend the whole table

This is a pretty quick glance, but the fact you can only click on the first line is a big clue, so I checked things overflow and height.
And, it looks to me like the TEXTAREA element is bigger than its parent. You have hardcoded the parent div to 34px and the textarea is also 34px, but with what looks like a total padding height of 16px, so the total height will be close to 50px, I think.
You don't have a box-sizing set, so by default it should be using the content size, which doesn't include padding.
And while the textarea hides overflow, its parent does not, so when the textarea breaks outside the input-element, part of it will likely be unclickable but visible.

The height 34px sets the data cell height. If I change that then the whole row changes with the data cell. Initially, the parent and child are the same height. When the user clicks the height is dynamically adjusted using adjustTextareaHeight. In the input-element parent I can do height: autoso its always the same height as of the textarea. But if I adjust the .description-column-cell` height, then the whole table row changes height.
